# How shell processes the content of command line in order to execute?

Tags: shell, command-line, process

How shell processes the content of command line in order to execute?

1. Command first and then option and arguments.
2. Dividing command line into segments.
3. Processes from beginning to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"shell" is a generic word for `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh` and all.

For all those shells, there is a man page (e.g. `man bash`) which details how command is expanded before execution (variable `$foo` are replaced by content, `fu*` in replaced by `fun funny` (provided thoses files exixts) and the like).

You can debug simple command using

```
echo my-command ${foo} fu*
```

More complex command (having a pipe (`|`) for instance) can be debugged by setting set -x before the command.

```
set -x
my-command ${foo} fu* | while read x 
do

done
set +x
```

However, this looks like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Answer (score 1):

First field on the command line is the command to execute, referred by special variable `$0`. Whatever comes after that, are just plain arguments to the executable, referred to as `$1`, `$2`, ... `$n`, and it is the `$0`'s responsibility to handle those, not the shell's

Comment: So after first field it execute character wise or word?

Comment: `$0` is a whole word, not chopped up character-by-character. I'm wondering where you are going with this ? What's on your mind ? Are you having an issue with some command ?

Answer (score 1):

The process of parsing (as it is called) a command line is a rather long and complex process which needs a sub-chapter of a book to make it justice as [described here for ksh](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/ksh/ch07_03.htm) (for example).

In general, in very simple terms (which fail to make justice to many needed details), each token (a word limited mostly by spaces), after being identified as an argument, is processed as found from left to right, and then given to the command as expanded arguments (re-directions are special).

Please read the book for a better description, understand that the above is very simplistic.